# Convert Checkpoint in tensorflow into HDF5

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to convert the weights in tensorflow model into a hdf5 so that i can use it as a pre-train model for some other network. How would i do it ?

Comment: What did you do so far? Where are ou stuck? I would say you have extract a numpy array from tensorflow and then insert it into hdf5.

Comment: I have trained a model and stored it as a checkpoint.  Now i would like to have a quite different model which uses 5 layers from pre-trained one.  So, I need to initialize weights and bias from pretrained model to new model. How do we that ?